# Prove that $2n\choose n$ divides $LCM(1,2,3,...,2n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What I did:

L = $LCM(1,2,...,2n)$

M = $2n\choose n$

If we can show that the exponent of any prime in the prime factorization of M is less than that in L, the problem is solved.

So, $e_p(M) \leq e_p(L)$ for all prime p.    ($e_p(M)$ means the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $M$)

Bye Legendre's formula, $e_p(M) = e_p((2n)!) - 2e_p(n!) = \sum_{r\geq1}\lfloor \frac{2n}{p^r}\rfloor - 2\sum_{r\geq1} \lfloor \frac{n}{p^r}\rfloor$

$e_p(L) =$ largest $m$ so that $p^m \leq 2n$ or $m = \lfloor\frac{\log 2n}{\log p}\rfloor$

Problem is, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be a prime, notice that by [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) $v_p(\binom{2n}{n}$) is equal to the number of carries when adding $n+n$ in base $p$. The number of carries is at most $ d-1$ where $d$ is the number of digits of $2n$ in base $p$. Notice that $p^{d-1} \leq 2n$ so $v_p(L) \geq d$, as was desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe an another way you can follow.

Now we fix our notation that $d_{\ell}:=LCM(1,2,....,\ell)$ for integer $\ell>0.$ Then the idea is to consider the integral for $1\leq j\leq k$ that
\begin{align*}
I(j,k):=\int_{0}^{1}x^{j-1}(1-x)^{k-j}~dx.    
\end{align*}
Then use binomial theorem to expand $(1-x)^{k-j}$ and then
\begin{align*}
I(j,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-j}{{k-j}\choose{i}}(-1)^{i}\int_{0}^{1}x^{i+j-1}~dx=\sum_{i=0}^{k-j}(-1)^{i}{{k-j}\choose{i}}\frac{1}{i+j}\in\frac{1}{d_{k}}\mathbb{Z}\tag{$\dagger$},
\end{align*}
where the last is true since $j+i\in\{j,j+1,...,j+(k-j)=k\}$ is a divisor of $d_{k}.$

On the other hand, if $0<y<1$ then we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{k}{{k-1}\choose{j-1}}y^{j-1}I(j,k)&=\sum_{j=1}^{k}{{k-1}\choose{j-1}}y^{j-1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{j-1}(1-x)^{k-j}~dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{j=1}^{k}{{k-1}\choose{j-1}}(1-x)^{k-j}(xy)^{j-1}~dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{{k-1}\choose{j}}(1-x)^{k-j-1}(xy)^{j}~dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x+xy)^{k-1}~dx\\
&=\frac{(1-x+xy)^{k}}{k(y-1)}~\bigg|_{0}^{1}\\
&=\frac{y^{k}-1}{k(y-1)}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{k}y^{j-1},
\end{align*}
where we can obtain the series in the third equation of the integral as we just demonstrate the series of the second equation of the integral and rearrange the index.

So compare the coefficients of the both sides to give
\begin{align*}
j{{k}\choose{j}}I(j,k)=k{{k-1}\choose{j-1}}I(j,k)=1\quad\text{ for }1\leq j\leq k, 
\end{align*}
here we used the identity $\displaystyle j{{k}\choose{j}}=k{{k-1}\choose{j-1}}.$

So combine the result of $(\dagger)$,  we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{d_{k}}\mathbb{Z}\ni I(j,k)=\frac{1}{j{{k}\choose{j}}},    
\end{align*}
as $1\leq j\leq k$. This shows that $\displaystyle j{{k}\choose{j}}$ is a divisor of $d_{k}$ for $1\leq j\leq k.$

Now take $k=2n$ and $j=n$ to see that $\displaystyle n{{2n}\choose{n}}$ is a divisor of $d_{2n}.$ This tells us that $d_{2n}$ has a divisor $\displaystyle {{2n}\choose{n}}.$